Install gnome alongside plasma Ubuntu studio 24.04 GDM fails to start
When I did a fresh install of 24.04 I got the plasma desktop instead of Gnome no idea why.
I used apt-get to install Gnome and when I ran the  config I chose GDM. On reboot I got error: failed to start GDM. I then got the black screen and blinking cursor.
After much searching I managed to get to the command line and used startx, got a blue screen? I ran the  gdm setup and chose ssdm (I think) Now back on plasma.
Also last Nvidia update leaves me with Apt-Get complaining about the Driver not installed correctly. Seems there is a bug with Nvidia installer at the moment.
Cheers for any advice.
Bob

Your details are a little confusing; you mention two releases; firstly its 24.04 but then have tagged your question as being about 22.04, so which release is it??  Ubuntu Studio uses the KDE Plasma desktop, so expecting GNOME makes no sense (long ago Ubuntu Studio used the Xfce desktop, but that wasn't GNOME either). If you want GNOME, you can install Ubuntu Desktop which will give you the GNOME desktop, then run the Ubuntu Studio Installer to add the Ubuntu Studio components to your existing Ubuntu or flavor desktop (https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-installer/)

If you're using Ubuntu Studio 22.04 LTS; the release notes can be read at https://ubuntustudio.org/2022/04/ubuntu-studio-22-04-lts-released/ but given you also mention 24.04 the release notes for Ubuntu Studio 24.04 LTS the release notes can be found at https://ubuntustudio.org/ubuntu-studio-24-04-lts-release-notes/

So Sorry I used wrong tag it's 24.04 LTS also Didn't realise plasma was the default, I seemed to remember the xfce. Thanks for the info.
